# Android - Notification alarm sound

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm

I have implemented a notification with an alarm sound like this:

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Alarm", title + " (alarm)", pi);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if(alarmSound == null){
        alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        if(alarmSound == null){
            alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
    }
    note.sound = alarmSound;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    manager.notify(id, note);
```

The sound of the alarm plays, but the problem I'm facing is that it keeps playing all the time until I drag down the notification bar. While this is playing, I'm showing an activity as a dialog (popup) with some information about the current alarm playing.
I want to be able to cancel this alarm sound in the button I have in the dialog (popup activity).

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: can you put complete code pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to cancel the sound just us `manager.cancel(id)` in your dialog button click the id is the id you set when you created the notification with `manager.notify(id,note)`

Comment: but will it no remove my notification as well?

Comment: I want to keep the notification, but remove the sound. If I use normal notification sound, it sounds once, but using the alarm sound, it repeats itself

Comment: if you dont want to remove the notification then you have to use `MediaPlayer` to play the sound and not a notification. you can play the sounf when your pending intent fires

Comment: alright, I'll look into that! How can I stop the media player from another activity then?

Comment: you start the sound in that activity and cancle it in that activity with `MediaPlayer's` `stop` method

Comment: Just a thought, before you dive into MediaPlayer, you may get favorable results simply by adding Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND to note.defaults. I've done this (testing on Galaxy S3, Android OS 4.0.4), and it doesn't play all the time like in your situation.